# Reuse base path variable in Ansible variable block

Tags: variables, ansible

I have a variable block for a specific app, that contains child-variables. One of them is a base directory, that I want to re-use in different other child-variables like this:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    app:
      base_dir: /opt/app
      data_dir: "{{ app.base_dir }}/data"

  tasks:
    - name: Test
      shell: "echo data dir: {{ app.data_dir }}"
```

`app.data_dir` should be `/opt/app/data` but without forcing me to repeat `/opt/app` for every variable. But it doesn't work, instead I got a very long exception from Ansible:

> TASK [Test]
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ Monday 16 December 2019  11:13:55 +0100 (0:00:02.417)
>   0:00:02.439 ******* fatal: [192.168.122.91]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An
>   unhandled exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{
>   app.base_dir }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: An unhandled
>   exception occurred while templating '{u'data_dir': u'{{ app.base_dir
>   }}/data', u'base_dir': u'/opt/app'}'. Error was a , original message: recursive loop
>   detected in template string: {{ app.base_dir }}/data"}

Looks like Ansible do some recursion. How can I reference to `app.base_dir`? Tried `{{ base_dir }}` as well. This gave me an error that it's not existing, so I assume that Ansible search it in the global scope and not in `app`.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that we need to prefix the full variable path with `vars`

```
  vars:
    app:
      base_dir: /opt/app
      data_dir: "{{ vars.app.base_dir }}/data"
```

When running `ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml -vv` it gaves the expected output of `opt/app/data`:

```
TASK [Test] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/daniel/cnx6-kvm/ansible/test.yml:8
Monday 16 December 2019  11:17:31 +0100 (0:00:02.452)       0:00:02.475 *******
changed: [192.168.122.91] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo data dir: /opt/app/data", "delta": "0:00:00.054859", "end": "2019-12-16 11:17:30.744850", "rc": 0, "start": "2019-12-16 11:17:30.689991", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "data dir: /opt/app/data", "stdout_lines": ["data dir: /opt/app/data"]}
```